# How can I use the 'leaks' command line tool on an application running in a device?

Tags: ios7, memory-leaks, xcode4.6, xcode-instruments

I want to use the `leaks` command-line tool to analyse my leaks. I initially used Instruments, but somehow all the leaks were solved. Later, the app got rejected, giving leaks as the issue.

From the logs, I learnt that the `leaks` tool is being used to test instead of Instruments, and finding leaks which are not being shown in Instruments.

Can anybody help me with this?

Also, I don't have and don't want to use a jailbroken device.